# Profile2 Registration Path module integration with LoginToboggan Non-authenticated role

Tags: users, authentication-authorization

I have a site where there are 2 independent user roles, *USER_TYPE_1* and *USER_TYPE_2*. [Profile2 RegPath](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) module gives me the two unique registration pages for unique role assignments. With [LoginToboggan](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan), all new users get a 3rd type of role, *NON_AUTHENTICATED*, which is removed after verification.

I'm looking for users to get limited permissions (non-authenticated role) before verification, then more permissions (*USER_TYPE_2* or *USER_TYPE_2* depending on which registration form they used) after verification.

Answer (score 1):

LoginToboggan invokes [`hook_user_update()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_update/7) when it validates an email. It sets the property `$account->logintoboggan_email_validated` to `TRUE` so you can test it upon your own hook invocation. Inside your hook_user_update invocation, you can use the profile2 function [`profile2_load_by_user($user)`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!profile2!profile2.module/function/profile2_load_by_user/7) to load the validated user object profile to determine which additional roles need to be set.

Comment: Seems the right direction, but is there no caveat? Did someone actually try this? Afaik the profile2-specific role needs to be present during the registration itself, then removed for the verification phase, and then re-added when verification is complete. But what happens if a user edits his/her account while not yet verified? will this damage the profile2, because the role is missing? or will the profile2 simply not show up in the form, because the role is missing (which could be confusing)?

Comment: Maybe it is safer to give up on this password-on-registration option.